# PyQT - modifying main window widgets from other functions

Tags: python, pyqt

A PyQT beginner question.  I'm wondering how to do something like the following - modify widgets in the main window from outside the main window class.  Like so:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):    

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()        
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.progressBar.setMaximum(100)
        self.ui.progressBar.setMinimum(0)
        self.ui.progressBar.setValue(0)

        self.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.slotDoStuff)

    def slotDoStuff(self):
        AnotherFunction()


def AnotherFunction():    
    modify progress bar here...
```

Is there a way to do something like this? I'd like to subclass the event handlers for various main window actions and not have them all in the MainWindow class.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there's a much better way to connect signals to slots on PyQt:

```
self.button.clicked.connect(self.method)
```

You can use lambda functions to pass extra arguments to methods.

```
def do_stuff(arg)
     #do stuff with arg
```

Then you call

```
self.button1.clicked.connect(lambda : do_stuff('btn one'))
self.button2.clicked.connect(lambda : do_stuff('btn two'))
```

You can pass whatever you want, including your MainWindow instance to be modified