# PyQt save to clipboard in a slot

Tags: pyqt

How can I save some text to clipboard by pressing button? `clipboard.setText("gg")` works by itself

```
widget.connect(button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), clipboard.setText("text") )
```

throw error, you can only use `instance.methodName`

```
widget.connect(button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), clipboard, QtCore.SLOT('setText("text")') )
```

do nothing.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's a much better way to connect signals to slots on PyQt:

```
button.clicked.connect(self.method)
```

You can use lambda functions to pass extra arguments to methods.
Then you call

```
button1.clicked.connect(lambda : clipboard.setText('btn one'))
button2.clicked.connect(lambda : clipboard.setText('btn two'))
```

When you pass a function call, in fact the interpreter is evaluating the call and trying to pass the result to the SIGNAL/SLOT connection. That's why your first example doesn't work.

I've written something similar here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/...from-other-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024990/pyqt-modifying-main-window-widgets-from-other-functions)